# How to configure apticron to just report security / critical updates?

Tags: linux, cron, apt

We're going to try out apticron, but we don't want to know about every package that could be updated -- only the security / critical updates.  How do we configure apticron to do this?

PS -- yes, we are subscribed to the Debian security announcement list.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I created a new sources.list file which held only the sources I wanted Apticron to work with

And then I changed the Apticron code so it will use the file I created.

```
sudo grep "-security" /etc/apt/sources.list | sudo grep -v "#" > /etc/apt/security.sources.list
```

Above command will create a new sources list specifically for security.

Inside the /usr/sbin/apticron code I made the following changes.

- Update the package lists

  ```
  /usr/bin/apt-get -qq update -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list || true
  ```
- Get the list of packages which are pending an upgrade

  ```
  PKGNAMES=`/usr/bin/apt-get -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list -q -y --ignore-hold --allow-unauthenticated -s dist-upgrade | \
  /bin/grep ^Inst | /usr/bin/cut -d\  -f2 | /usr/bin/sort`
  ```

It did work for me. [This link](https://kura.io/2011/09/21/debianubuntu-upgrade-security-packages-only-a-better-way-to-do-it/) contains tutorial how to create and use a different source.list for apt-get.

Comment: The link to the tutorial is broken/down. You'll need to edit the bash Apticron application file `/usr/sbin/apticron`

Answer (score 0):

The 'unattend-upgrades' package actually looks promising for what you intend,
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/automatic-updates.html
[Should I have to enable automatic update on Debian lenny stable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/22324/should-i-have-to-enable-automatic-update-on-debian-lenny-stable)

Comment: Hi user1125087 I'd rather not use an automated unattended updater.  I'd rather test out the update myself on a test machine first, then do the update manually.  Also, if some code breaks all of a sudden, and if I'm using an automated unattended updater tool, I'd have to remember that such a tool could have pushed the update that cause the code to fail.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the, "APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade" option to 0? This would stop auto install but would still download the update/s?

Comment: If you're selling expedicious you could then write a script to cross reference between the apticron email and unattend's downloads? Thinking about a cleaner solution though...